# List Messages using Gmail API NodeJS authorization error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I wrote a simple code to list the messages from my gmail account. However, on I get a 401 error. My code is as below

```
const gmailKey = google.gmail({version: 'v1', oauth2Client});

var initialRequest = gmailKey.users.messages.list({
    'userId': 'me'
});
getPageOfMessages(initialRequest, []);

var getPageOfMessages = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        result = result.concat(resp.messages);
        var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
            if (nextPageToken) {
                request = gmail.users.messages.list({
                    'userId': 'me',
                    'pageToken': nextPageToken
                });
                getPageOfMessages(request, result);
            }else{
                callback(result);
            }
    });
};
```

And the error is

```
code: 401,
errors:
[{ domain: 'global',
   reason: 'required',
   message: 'Login Required',
   locationType: 'header',
   location: 'Authorization' }]
```

The oauth2Client is as below

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URL
);
```

I used the same *oauth2Client* to get the access token and also have verified the same in the *.credentials* subsection. I also ensured that the *oauth2Client*  initializing the *gmailKey* contains the appropriate credentials.

How can I resolve the gmail authorization problem?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

If you're still having this issue, the problem with not setting the authorisation is in the first line of code you pasted:

`const gmailKey = google.gmail({version: 'v1', oauth2Client});`

The correct way to set oauth2Client is:

`const gmailKey = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client });`

or

`google.options({ auth: oauth2Client }); // sets globally
const gmailKey = google.gmail('v1');`

Answer (score 0):

> 'Login Required',

Means exactly that you need to be authenticated in order to access a users data.

You may want to consult [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) or this but its drive you will have to alter it slightly [Oauth2 user agent](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)

```
var GoogleAuth; // Google Auth object.
function initClient() {
  gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
      'clientId': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
      'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest']
  }).then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
  });
}
```

If you are using node you could try the [node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Comment: I did setup the _GoogleAuth_ object as you suggested but the error is the same. Can you please specify how you defined the _gapi_ object and how you called the _users.messages.list_ function

Comment: you should consult the [auth](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests) sample page if you want to use the Google apis js client library rather than the google apis nodejs client library.